# Am I interpreting these correctly?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity, books, sentence-meaning

Right now I am reading a chapter in Walden. There are two instances where I seem to be missing the mark because the summaries I read online (ie Sparknotes) do not corroborate the interpretation I'm getting. Here we go:

> 1) "However, I let him keep the ten dollars and the farm too, for I
>   had carried it far enough; or rather, to be generous, I sold him the
>   farm for just what I gave for it, and, as he was not a rich man, made
>   him a present of ten dollars, and still had my ten cents, and seeds,
>   and materials for a wheelbarrow left. I found thus that I had been a
>   rich man without any damage to my poverty. But I retained the
>   landscape, and I have since annually carried off what it yielded
>   without a wheelbarrow."

-------Does this mean Thoreau gave away his ten cents, seeds and materials or did he keep them? It says "still had my ten cents..." but I don't know who has them. Also, it says, "I retained the landscape" which suggests to me that he abandoned everything else.

> 2) "I have thus surveyed the country on every side within a dozen
>   miles of where I live. In imagination I have bought all the farms in
>   succession, for all were to be bought, and I knew their price. I
>   walked over each farmer's premises, tasted his wild apples, discoursed
>   on husbandry with him, took his farm at his price, at any price,
>   mortgaging it to him in my mind; even put a higher price on it- took
>   everything but a deed of it-took his word for his deed, for I dearly
>   love to talk- cultivated it, and him too to some extent, I trust, and
>   withdrew when I had enjoyed it long enough, leaving him to carry it
>   on. This experience entitled me to be regarded as a sort of
>   real-estate broker by my friends."-----

The summaries I've read suggest that Thoreau actually attempted to buy the homes without any actual intention of paying for them. Personally, I think Thoreau just imagined this all in his mind.

Answer (score 2):

1. The phrase “still had my ten cents” appears in the first sentence
   of the first excerpt — a long, rambling sentence that begins “However, I”
   and appears to have “I” as its subject throughout. 
   The only real confusion comes from the phrase “as *he* was not a rich man”,
   but that’s a subordinate clause, and so “he” should not be taken
   to be the subject that goes with the following verbs.
2. I believe that your interpretation is correct. 
   Early in this excerpt, we see “In imagination …”,
   and later on this is reinforced with “… in my mind”,
   so I don’t understand why anybody would believe
   that the author *actually* attempted to buy the homes.